# Different display of email signature in browser and MS Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

With the following code I styled my email signature and it looks good in different browsers. But in MS Outlook there is something wrong with the size and the line height.

```
<table aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  width="652" style="margin: 0; max-width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:'Calibri', sans-serif;font-size:10pt;overflow:hidden;padding-left:2px;word-break:normal;text-align:left;vertical-align:top" colspan="7">
      Some text<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/133x105.png?text=Image" width="133" alt="" style="display: block; margin: 0; padding-top:2px;max-width: 100%;" />
      </td>
    <td width="111" valign="top" style="padding-left:15px;">
      <p style="font-family:'Calibri', sans-serif;font-size:10pt; margin: 0;">
        <strong>John Doe</strong><br />Text
      </p>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/251x63.png?text=Image" width="251" alt="" style="display: block; margin: 0; max-width: 100%;" />
       </td>
    <td valign="top" colspan="4">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/142x63.png?text=Image" width="142" alt="" style="display: block; margin: 0; max-width: 100%;" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:15px;" colspan="2">
        <p style="font-family:'Calibri', sans-serif;font-size:9pt;line-height:12pt;">
        1234 5698 56
        </p>
      </td>
    <td valign="top" colspan="4">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="padding-left:15px;" colspan="2">
        <p style="font-family:'Calibri', sans-serif;font-size:9pt;line-height:10pt;">
        j.doe@domain.de<br>Comapny Name | Street | ZIP City
        </p>
      </td>
    <td valign="bottom">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/55x29.png?text=Image" width="55" alt="youtube" style="display: block; margin: 0; max-width: 100%;" /></a>
      </td>
    <td valign="bottom">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x29.png?text=Image" width="30" alt="Marbo Mediengruppe" style="display: block; margin: 0; max-width: 100%;" /></a>
      </td>
    <td valign="bottom">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x29.png?text=Image" width="30" alt="Instagram" style="display: block; margin: 0; max-width: 100%;" /></a>
      </td>
    <td valign="bottom">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/27x29.png?text=Image" width="27" alt="facebook" style="display: block; margin: 0; max-width: 100%;" /></a>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In browser it looks like as it should.
[image: signature in browser]

And in outlook it looks like
[image: signature in MS Outlook]

I tried to set up the line height without any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies. You can find supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.